# Agora Cloud class Room Login failed

Tags: react-native, electron, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

[image]

I am unable to login with agora educatuion web sdk

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/restful_authentication

Get your auth by following the instruction on that link.

go to your **env.local** and assign your auth to REACT_APP_AGORA_RESTFULL_TOKEN